# jQuery noConflict, or what?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a student and don't have much background in the code development field. I just have my website running and want to put jetmenu under my template (that's it!).

Here's the jetmenu

```
http://codecanyon.net/item/jet-responsive-megamenu/5719593
```

But once I put under the template, it's working only the parent menu, while the submenu itself won't work at all. I tried to open firebug and it said the "!@#@!@# is not a function"

Browse the web, and found the problem. That is, the template is using 2 library of jQuery in different version. Trying to implement some techie trick in noConflict but always no luck.

Here's the code.

```
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    sQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery().jetmenu();
    });
</script>
<script src="{$baseurl}/js/jetmenu.js"></script>
<script src="{$baseurl}/js/jquery.customSelect.js"></script>
```

I thought first I can refer like "xxQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true)" but if it needs to edit the whole the jquery code using the library (replace the $ with xxjQuery) will waste of time.

Comment: And that menu uses a really old version of jquery. yikes.

Comment: `sQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);` ?

Comment: Try using the menu without including jQuery 1.3.2

Comment: Hi All, have tried but doesn't work well.

Comment: Just one side note: having two jQuery versions in one page is just an awful idea for development. Whoever did that, was terribly wrong about something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could do something like that:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    var jq191 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    var jq132 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>

<script>

    jq191(document).ready(function() {

       // use the newer version to load the script
        jq191.getScript( "{$baseurl}/js/jetmenu.js" )
          .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
            console.log( textStatus );

            // locally override the $() to use the older version of jQuery
            var $ = jq132;

            // Use the loaded script
            $.jetmenu();

          })
          .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
            console.error( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
          });

        // use the newer one from now on
        $ = jq191;

    }); // ready

</script>
```

Also, you might find these solutions useful: [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

Comment: So @dekkard , the case is there's another important script built-in from template that using sQuery, and that's why whenever I done upload the one you gave (with edit in some part )

But the problem isn't fixed yet. In firebug console now I saw "$ is not a function" in many other script file. Thanks for great response anyway!